# subcribe to channel and like/dislike youtube video programmatically android

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

How to achieve from an android application which can subscribe, like or dislike a particular youtube video from android application side. And yes this is not so far, i also want callback for all of them like once user has like video then i want callback of that, too. I have searched and got some idea about YouTube Data API,but how to integrate it in my own app that is what i am confused. And is there any else way to achieve this, if someone have then kindly let me know.

Comment: No. I still don't get anything.

Answer (score 0):

To get ratings (like or dislike) you have to to take the *video_ID* and make a separate API request to get the details you want for the video.

Here are some of the Listener, you may use this specially for loading, playing and controlling video callback: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#Overview

You may use the  ['Get Started'](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/#How_It_Works), The document will help you to set up your development environment and use the Youtube Android Player API.

Comment: Yes, but how can i give rating(like/dislike) any video ? I know there is an Post API but how can i pass user's authentication parameter into that ?